# (Swift) Ex_Bad_Access in heightForRowAtIndexPath with Variable Row Height

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

First, the error:

```
 > Assertion failure in 
-[UITableView _dequeueReusableViewOfType:withIdentifier:], 
/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3232.3/UITableView.m:5978
    2014-06-18 17:49:51.887 Twitter App[21909:583896] \

***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',

 reason: 'invalid nib registered for identifier (CustomTimelineCell) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance'**
```

Second, the background: `TableViewController` pulls timeline from Twitter, parses it, updates the `tableView` which uses dynamic prototype custom cells. Each cell's height is calculated in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` by creating a dummy cell with that tweet's attributes then returning the height. That all works fine, but when leaving the view and going back via back the button, the view repeats that process and crashes.

Relevant Code:

```
var tweetsArray:NSArray = NSArray()
var accountStore:ACAccountStore = ACAccountStore()
var account:ACAccount = ACAccount()
var profileImages:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

let identifier:NSString = "CustomTimelineCell"

//viewWillAppear simply requests authorization and calls the following functions to do the work

func reloadTimeline() {

    requestAuthorization()

    var url: NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json")

    var params: NSDictionary = ["trim_user" : "false", "count" : "200"]

    var request: SLRequest = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter, requestMethod: SLRequestMethod.GET, URL: url, parameters: params)

    request.account = account

    // Execute the Request

    let requestHandler: SLRequestHandler = {responseData, urlResponse, error in

        if responseData {
            if urlResponse.statusCode >= 200 && urlResponse.statusCode < 300 {

                var error: NSError? = NSError()

                let feedData:NSArray? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &error) as? NSArray

                if feedData {
                    self.updateFeed(feedData!)
                    //println("Timeline Response: \(self.tweetsArray)")
                }
            }
            else {
                println("Response Status Code: \(urlResponse.statusCode)")
            }

        }
        if error {
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }

    request.performRequestWithHandler(requestHandler)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

}

func updateFeed(feedData: NSArray) {
    tweetsArray = feedData
    self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    tableView.reloadData()
    self.stopRefresh()

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    var cell : CustomTimelineCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath!) as CustomTimelineCell

    let currentTweet:NSDictionary = tweetsArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSDictionary

    let currentUser:NSDictionary = currentTweet.objectForKey("user") as NSDictionary

    cell.username.text = currentUser.objectForKey("name") as NSString!
    cell.tweetText.text = currentTweet.objectForKey("text") as NSString!
    cell.userImage.image = UIImage(named: "bird_twitter.png")

    // Adds and Configures Gesture Recognizer for Profile Image (uses segue made from unused IB gesture recognizer)
    if !cell.userImage.gestureRecognizers {

        cell.userImage.userInteractionEnabled = true

        var imageTapRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "profileImageTap")
        imageTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        imageTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        cell.userImage.addGestureRecognizer(imageTapRecognizer)

    }

    // May or may not be necessary, but including constraint resizing restrictions
    cell.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
    cell.username.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    cell.tweetText.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    cell.userImage.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    let imageDimension:CGSize = CGSize(width: 48, height: 48)
    cell.sizeThatFits(imageDimension)

    var usernameString = currentUser.objectForKey("name") as NSString!

    if profileImages.objectForKey(usernameString) {
        cell.userImage.image = profileImages.objectForKey(usernameString) as UIImage!
    }
    else {

        // Creates Concurrent Queue for Image Fetching
        var concurrentQueue:dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

        // Asynchronously get URL String and convert to NSURL
        dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, {

            var imageURLString:NSString = currentUser.objectForKey("profile_image_url") as NSString!

            var imageURL = NSURL(string: imageURLString)

            // Synchronously download image data and save to profileImages array (1 by 1)
            dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, {
                var imageData:NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL)

                self.profileImages.setObject((UIImage(data:imageData)), forKey: usernameString)
                })
            // In Main Queue, set the profileImage for each cell from newly populated array
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                cell.userImage.image = self.profileImages.objectForKey(usernameString) as UIImage!
                })
            })
    }

    return cell
}
```

The app always crashes here in this function (I don't know if everything is treated appropriately given how Swift deals with nil objects) at the `dequeueReusableCell` line.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {

    var currentTweet:NSDictionary = tweetsArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSDictionary

    var currentUser:NSDictionary = currentTweet.objectForKey("user") as NSDictionary
    var usernameString = currentUser.objectForKey("name") as NSString!
    var tweetTextString = currentTweet.objectForKey("text") as NSString!

    var prototypeCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? CustomTimelineCell

    if let customCell = prototypeCell {

        customCell.username.text = usernameString
        customCell.tweetText.text = tweetTextString
        customCell.userImage.image = UIImage(named: "bird_twitter.png")

        var size:CGSize = customCell.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)

        return size.height+1
    }
    else {

        var customCell:CustomTimelineCell = CustomTimelineCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CustomTimelineCell")
        customCell.username.text = usernameString
        customCell.tweetText.text = tweetTextString
        customCell.userImage.image = UIImage(named: "bird_twitter.png")

        var size:CGSize = customCell.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)

        return size.height+1
    }
}
```

I've looked up and down through StackOverflow for every error related to it and everything that popped up when trying to fix it, but nothing has worked. I don't know if it's because of the way Swift handles things, but I believe the problem is in either dequeuing the cell when returning to the view, or some connection didn't close before I left/returned. Any ideas?

Edit: Some new information which may be relevant: When scrolling through the tableView after it initially loads, -heightForRowAtIndexPath is called twice for each cell, and I can't understand why. Also, when returning to the tableView from another view, when it reloads, it calls -heightforRowAtIndexPath twice for the first few cells, but only once for the rest (0,1,0,1,2,3...). Is that related to the exc_bad_access crash?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: _'invalid nib registered for identifier (CustomTimelineCell) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance'_ : what does your xib look like?

Comment: I'm only using a storyboard, which has a navigation controller and tableviewcontroller, and in that is a tableview with a single prototype cell subclassed/identifier set as CustomTimelineCell. I'm not using a separate xib